# Exporting multiple bands From EarthEngine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I'm new to EarthEngine and I am having troubles exporting my RGB map as a GeoTIFF with the correct bands. When I try plotting this layer in R using tmap, it only has one layer. I tried making a custom visualization palette and it showed up as only one colour. I also created an NDVI map, but did not run into any of these issues.

Have you run into this issue?

Link to my script: https://code.earthengine.google.com/8f1dcba095fa961ed413d31c79eb1ff3

Relevent snippets of my Earthengine Code:

```
// Add the camp boundaries.
var campBoundaries = Map.addLayer(campBoundaries, {}, "Camp Boundaries");

var pointKT = ee.Geometry.Point([92.1635,21.2127]); //Get the location
Map.centerObject(pointKT); //Get to the location

//Date range.
var startDate= '2019-04-01'; // Start date for the 2-month period
var endDate = '2019-06-01'; // End date for the 2-month period

//Cloud cover mask
function cloudMask(KTimage){
    var scl = KTimage.select('SCL'); //Scene classification layer.
    var mask = scl.eq(3).or(scl.gte(7).and(scl.lte(10)));
    return KTimage.updateMask(mask.eq(0));
}

var KTimage = s2
              .filterBounds(pointKT)
              .filterDate(startDate,endDate)
              .map(cloudMask)
              .median();

//Get a preliminary map
Map.addLayer(KTimage, {
  bands:['B4','B3','B2'], 
  min:0, 
  max: [3000]
},'True Colour April-May');

// Define visualization parameters for the RGB export
var visParams = {
  bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], // RGB bands
  min: 0,
  max: 3000
};

var KTimageRGB = KTimage.visualize({bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], min: 0, max: 3000});
print("rgb",KTimageRGB);

//Export the RGB image
Export.image.toDrive({
  scale: 30,
  image: KTimageRGB,
  description: 'RGB_April_May',
  fileFormat: 'GeoTIFF',
  region: KTall,
  maxPixels: 1e13
});
```

Some Relevent R code.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
library(haven)
library(sf)
library(raster)
library(rasterVis)
library(tmap)
library(tmaptools)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(lattice)

options(maxprint=100) #Remove scientific notation.

# Switch to interactive viewing mode
tmap_mode("view") #toggle this for interactive maps.
#tmap_mode("plot") #toggle this for static maps.

veg_palette <- c(brewer.pal(9, "YlOrBr")[2], brewer.pal(9, "YlGn")[5], brewer.pal(9, "YlGn")[9])

#Map base layers
ndvi_ktall1 <-raster("/Users/obleodemandre/Desktop/Obleo's Code/R/Honours1/Data/Earthengine/NDVI_April_May_KTall1.tif")
rgb_ktall1 <- raster("/Users/obleodemandre/Desktop/Obleo's Code/R/Honours1/Data/Earthengine/RGB_April_May_KTall1.tif") #Not a true RBG layer. This is a single band raster

#Camp Boundaries
camp_boundaries_cb <- st_read("/Users/obleodemandre/Desktop/Obleo's Code/R/Honours1/Data/Camp boundary/200908_RRC_Outline_Camp_AL1.shp")
camp_boundaries_ktall <- camp_boundaries_cb[
  camp_boundaries_cb$Upazila == "Ukhia" & camp_boundaries_cb$Camp_Name != "Choukhali", ]
camp_boundaries_ktmain <- camp_boundaries_ktall[!camp_boundaries_ktall$Camp_Name %in% c("Camp 14", "Camp 15", "Camp 16"), ]

######################################
########Plotting the ndvi map.#############
######################################
tm_base_ndvi_ktall1 <- tm_shape(ndvi_ktall1) +
  tm_raster(style = "cont", palette = veg_palette, title = "NDVI") + 
  tm_layout(frame = FALSE)

tm_final_map_ktall1 <- tm_base_ndvi_ktall1 + 
  tm_shape(camp_boundaries_ktall) +
  tm_borders()

tm_final_map_ktall1

######################################
########Plotting the rgb map.#############
######################################

# Plotting the RGB map
tm_base_rgb_ktall1 <- tm_shape(rgb_ktall1) +
  tm_rgb() +
  tm_layout(frame = FALSE)

tm_final_map_rgb_ktall1 <- tm_base_rgb_ktall1 + 
  tm_shape(camp_boundaries_ktmain) +
  tm_borders()

# Print the final map
tm_final_map_rgb_ktall1

Error: Specified rgb(a) bands are 1, 2, 3 whereas the number of layers is 1
```

Verifying that the RGB map only has one layer

```
> nlayers(rgb_ktall1)
[1] 1
```